# How to use input in RNN model

Tags: python, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network, torchvision

I have some rnn model

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        # some code #
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.rnn(x)
        output = my_function(# here is a code to get input #)
        return x, output
```

And I need use input in my function in this model. Сan i do it somehow

Comment: what's your data format?

Comment: I'm using Tensors
`model(data)`, where data is (1,34,768) Tensor, where each input has size (1,768)